# How to write one page scrolling url in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm writing one page web template

<`a href="/newhotel/advanced/frontend/web/#reviews" class="smoothScroll">Portfolio</a>`

need to add `#reviews` into yii2 url, how to add this?

Comment: #reviews what is a controller ? an action? a tagRef  inside a page .?

Comment: its an id for the section e.g `<section class="boxes" id="reviews">`, its a one page template it scrolls to the particular section when click on nav bar, the url I showed in question works like charm but I need in yii2 format

Comment: there is nothing in controller

Comment: I have posted an answer ...hope is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Url::to

```
 use yii\helpers\Url;

<a href="<?= Url::to(['yourController/yourActionindex', '#' => 'yourHrefTagname'])?>">
```

in your case i think could be

```
 <a href="<?= Url::to(['site/index', '#' => 'reviews'])?>">
```

Comment: Awesome `<?= Html::a('Make Reservation', ['site/index','#' => 'review', ['class' => 'smoothScroll']]) ?> ` I did like this  :)
thank you

Comment: I don't urderstand  ... the answer is right  ? or you have some problem?

Comment: yes your answer is right I was having trouble for `#` you solved it by `'#' => 'yourHrefTagname'` :)